# (Haskell/GTK/Glade) read strings from entrys and then print the sum

Tags: haskell, gtk, glade

i created a gui program using haskell + GTK + Glade

the gui looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRXIf.png

i want to display the sum of the credit hours but the problem is it concatenates the numbers instead of calculating the sum (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRXIf.png )

my code:

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Glade

main = do
    initGUI
    Just xml    <- xmlNew "program.glade"
    window      <- xmlGetWidget xml castToWindow "window1"
    onDestroy window mainQuit

    closeButton <- xmlGetWidget xml castToButton "button2"
    onClicked closeButton $ do
        widgetDestroy window


    entry1credit       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry13"

    entry2credit       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry14"

    entry3credit       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry15"

    entry4credit       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry16"

    entry5credit       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry17"

    entry6credit       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry18"

    creditText       <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry "entry19"
    calcButton <- xmlGetWidget xml castToButton "button1"

    onClicked calcButton $ do
        credit1 <- get entry1credit entryText
        credit2 <- get entry2credit entryText
        credit3 <- get entry3credit entryText
        credit4 <- get entry4credit entryText
        credit5 <- get entry5credit entryText
        credit6 <- get entry6credit entryText
    let a = credit1++credit2++credit3++credit4++credit5++credit6
        set creditText [ entryText := ""++a ]
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

the problem is at this part ,,, i don't know how to convert string to int in haskell :

```
onClicked calcButton $ do
            credit1 <- get entry1credit entryText
            credit2 <- get entry2credit entryText
            credit3 <- get entry3credit entryText
            credit4 <- get entry4credit entryText
            credit5 <- get entry5credit entryText
            credit6 <- get entry6credit entryText
        let a = credit1++credit2++credit3++credit4++credit5++credit6
            set creditText [ entryText := ""++a ]
```

Comment: `read` from Prelude converts a string into whatever you want. You'll have to slap on a type annotation to tell the compiler which type you expect to get from it.

Comment: thanks .... now i have another error........ let x = (read credit1 :: Float)+(read credit2 :: Float) set creditText [ entryText := ""+(read x :: String) ] ....... Couldn't match type Float with [Char]

Comment: problem solved by using `show` ....... my fixed code is: `let x = (read credit1 :: Float)+(read credit2 :: Float)
        set creditText [ entryText := ""++(show x) ]`